# Is there a jpa or hibernate property to make all queries case insensitive

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for an elegant way to make all queries in  jpa hibernate case insensitive. The under lying database is Oracle

Individually in the query we can write like

```
upper(entity.field) = upper(:value) 

or 

Restrictions.eq(entity.field, value).ignoreCase()
```

Is there a way we don't have to do this individually in each query but handle it for the entire session

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - I'm not aware of such a property or configuration option, and there are good reasons why there can't be any (see below).

Your question is a bit misleading.
The query language (JPQL) itself is indeed case insensitive. Not only are the query **keywords** case insensitive, but it's even case insensitive for identifiers where Java is case sensitive. For example, you can have `myVar`, `myvar`, and `MYVAR` in the same Java class, and they would all be different instance variables. If this class is turned into an @Entity and you write a query with that entity, for JPA it would be ambiguous which variable you mean. (Not tested though, so not sure what kind of error that produces.)

What you actually seem to want is ***string comparisons*** to be case insensitive, which is a different matter altogether. These comparisons are performed on the DB side, so technically this is up to the database how the `=` operator is implemented. In practice, I'm not aware of any relational database that treats string values case insensitive.

Since you mention Oracle - in Oracle, ***identifiers*** are indeed case insensitive (unless quoted) and are automatically uppercased by the DB. This is kind of a legacy from the 1980s when most of the text in computers was usually written uppercase (see MSDOS, FAT filesystem, BASIC programming language, etc.).

This however does not mean that the string ***values*** in the DB columns are treated case insensitive. This would be rather impractical, since there would be no way to actually check for real equality. Therefore, even in Oracle, `'foo' = 'FOO'` evaluates to `false`.